# ANTLR 4 + Portable Class Library

Tags: antlr, portable-class-library, antlr4

I have been trying to use ANTLR 4 to create a parser that will run in a .net PCL.  The parser generation can use whatever, but the parser itself has to run in a PCL as it will be deployed to mobile devices.

There is a PCL runtime for ANTLR 4 [here](https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs).  It does build.  But I can't figure out how to setup ANTLR as a whole to generate a PCL-compatible parser.  How can I do that?

Comment: William, if you are looking for *any* PCL ready *math* parser, you could also take a look at the [YAMP](https://github.com/FlorianRappl/YAMP) project, which provides a maximum portable PCL library with practically all functionality of the original library.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson It would be nice if the YAMP NuGet package included support for PCLs.  Right now it looks like you need to compile from source if you want to use it from a PCL.

Comment: What happens when you use the normal C# code that ANTLR generates in a PCL which references the PCL ANTLR runtime?  Do you get errors for missing APIs or what?

Comment: @DanielPlaisted, I agree. Florian Rappl is the author of YAMP and maintainer of the NuGet package, I have only contributed the PCL adaptations. I'll check if he is interested in updating the NuGet packages with PCL.

Comment: I now placed the portable version online via NuGet. YAMP (v1) is at the moment not actively developed, however, if there are bugs or feature requests I am willing to help.